# UISegmentedControl different behavior deployed on iOS 5 & iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

iOS5

```
 NONE    |    Center Blur    |     B/W
```

iOS5.1

```
 NONE    | Center Blur       |     B/W
```

The Center Blur layouts well on Target iOS 5. However , on iOS 5.1 , the title layouts wired.
I look into the UISegmentedControl head file , UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled claims to be deprecated.

I need to find some solution to replace the current implementation. Do I need to place a lot of bg img into the segmented control ?  Anyone got any good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, even while the docs don't show that, the `UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled` is deprecated, so should no longer use it. It's a known issue (http://openradar.appspot.com/11038316), with a regression to 5.0, where it worked.

If you want a similar design, yes, you should go through the pain of coding it yourself. Or as a workaround, as @Hlung says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883767/what-should-i-use-instead-of-the-deprecated-uisegmentedcontrolstylebezeled-in-io), you could use a `UISegmentedControlStyleBar` with increased height.